# How to ping google.com via particular IP(by explicitly mentioning) in Linux(windriver linux)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ping

How to ping google.com via particular IP (by explicitly mentioning the IP) in Linux(windriver linux)?

In freebsd I had an option as below.

```
ping -S 10.8.114.30 google.com
```

Here `-S` is for source address. I am trying to ping google.com via 10.8.114.30.

Do we have a similar option available in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the interface option `-I` with either an address

```
ping -I 10.8.114.30 www.google.com
```

or an interface name

```
ping -I eth0 www.google.com
```